# Incorrect format of a JSON for generate an JSON object with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a web that draws a tree. **inicio_pru.php** creates a JSON which represents the tree.This JSON is passed to a JavaScript file for creting the tree.

**inicio_pru.php**, is called in two different moments, first , when the page is charged , it creates the JSON and passes it to **example_pru.js** in order this can draw it. 2nd, when the tree is already created, and user clicks a node of the tree, this invoques **inicio_pru.php** from **example_pru.js**  with an object **XMLHttpRequest** and **inicio_pru.php** generates the JSON the same way as the 1rst time and this is sent to the **XMLHttpRequest** with an "echo" command.

It Works in the first case, but not in the second that generates the following error:

```
Unexpected token '
```

**inicio_pru.php**:

```
function main_p ($ID,$tipo_var,$desc_var,$idnodo,$t_ancestros) {
  ......

  //Here, $arbol is saved in the correct format 


  if ($tipo_var=='BIFURCADORES'){
    $file = fopen("archivo.txt", "w");
    //$file = fopen($desc_var.".txt", "w");
    fwrite($file, $arbol . PHP_EOL);
    fclose($file);
    } 

    return $arbol;

 }



 //main program



 if (!is_null($idnodo)) {


    // main_p , has saved  $arbol with each field of the JSON in double quotes

    $arbol=main_p($ID,$tipo_var,$desc_var,$idnodo,$t_ancestros);

  //this sentence has saved  $arbol at the discwith each field of the JSON without double quotes
    exec('echo '.$arbol. ' >>/tmp/pista11', $output, $error);


  //This is sent to example1_json_pru.js throght an objet    XMLHttpRequest 
    echo $arbol;

  }
  else 

    $arbol=main_p($ID,$tipo_var,$desc_var,$idnodo,$t_ancestros);
```

As you can see, $arbol, is saved in two files:

archivo.txt , correct, it place each field in double quotes, but in pista11, fileds appear without these double quotes:

```
archivo.txt , (correct):

{"id":"53530","name":"Bifurcadores <ul ....

pista11 , (incorrect):

{id:53530,name:Bifurcadores <ul  ......
```

In **inicio_pru.php** at the "else" sentence,  **$arbol** is passed to another .php  , that sends it to  .js **example_pru.js**, and it works:

**grafos_template_otro_json_fr_pru.php:**

```
   <!--  Files -->

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"      src="../mapas/assets/js/example1_json_pru.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var datos=<?php echo $arbol ; ?>;
     var ID=<?php echo $ID ; ?>;
     var tipo_var=<?php echo $tipo_var ; ?>;

   </script>

    </head>

           <body onload="init(datos,1,ID,tipo_var);">
```

(init is una function of example1_json_pru.js)

However, when **init_pru.php** is called from the **XMLHttpRequest** and it pases $arbol to  **example1_json_pru.js** this way, it doesn't work, and generates the error mencioned before:

**XMLHttpRequest:**

```
    onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
        label.id = node.id;            
        label.innerHTML = node.name;
        label.onclick = function(){

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "inicio_pru.php";
        var params = "idnodo="+ node.id + "&ID=" + ID + "&id_arbol=" + tipo_var;
         http.open("POST", url, true);

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.send(params);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

        //astonishingly,  alert shows the fields of the JSON in quotes despite pista11 (file saved just before sending $arbol XMLHttpRequest object), showed them wihthout double quotes




               alert (http.responseText);
               //This is the sentence that generates error:
               json=JSON.parse(http.responseText);

               st.loadJSON(json);
               //compute node positions and layout
               st.compute();
               //optional: make a translation of the tree
               st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");
               st.onClick(node.id);    

            }
           }

         };
```

Could you please help me? Thank you very much indeed

Comment: Probably want `exec("echo '$arbol' >>/tmp/pista11", $output, $error);` but maybe need some escaping on `$arbol` as well.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that your json has invalid format.

```
 archivo.txt , (correct):
{"id":"53530","name":"Bifurcadores

pista11 , (incorrect):

{id:53530,name:Bifurcadores
```

in above example you can see you are missing " " in variables and values.

Comment: But when i make an alert in .js alert (http.responseText) this appears like archivo.txt .... And  main_p saves archivo.txt correctly and one sentence after , pista11 appears without quotes ... I can't understand why ...

Comment: I think the issue is with json parsing.. you are missing something while putting data or fetching data.

Comment: I did this : json=JSON.parse(http.responseText.trim().replace(/\\'/g,"\\\\'")); and it works but it's not the proper solution because this unformat hte menus inside JSON : {"id":"53530","name":"Bifurcadores <ul class=\'menu\' style=\'display:none\' etc ... Too much "\\\\"